# The constructor XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Iam trying to read data from an excel file, i am using the following code :

```
    File Excel = new File("C:\\Users\\data.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Excel);

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

but i am getting the compilation error as 
The constructor `XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream)` is undefined

Comment: If you have the `File`, why are you trying to use an `InputStream`? The [Apache POI documentation is very clear on why you shouldn't normally, and why using a File directly is almost always better!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: Hi..I am unable to resolve the issue,,,could you please send me the code snippet?

Comment: Umm, the link I gave already includes the code you need to use to open an XSSFWorkbook from a File!

Comment: Better yet, use WorkbookFactory.create to open the file, which will work on both Excel 97-2003 and Excel 2007+ files. WorkbookFactory.create also lets you specify if you want to open the workbook as read-only and specify a password if the workbook is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

try this one
Its work for me
Successfully.........

```
try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filename))) {
                **Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);**
```

try{

```
        String filename="C:\\Users\\NIKITA\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NickPrac\\exceldatabase.xlsx";
        out.print(filename);
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filename))) {
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" , "root" , "root");

            String jdbc_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO employee"+"VALUES(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement preStatement = con.prepareStatement(jdbc_insert_sql);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            System.out.println("last row number is========="+sheet.getLastRowNum());
            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                int empId = (int) (row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
                String empName = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String empEmail = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

                String sql="insert into employee "+"values('"+empId+"','"+empName+"','"+empEmail+"')";
                preStatement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                preStatement.execute();
                System.out.println("Records inserted.........."+i);

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        out.println("Error");
    }
```

`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void setExcelFile(String Path, String SheetName) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        try {

            // Open the Excel file

            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);

            // Access the required test data sheet

            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Users\\data.xlsx");
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw (e);

        }

    }
```

Comment: This uses non-Apache POI classes, opens the file potentnailly twice, and uses a hard-coded path...